# Entering data down column using tab or return key in QGIS for Mac?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, editing, osx

I have many shapefiles that require I manually populate data fields in an attribute table.  I am using QGIS in a Mac system.

For speed and efficiency, I prefer to use the tab or return carriage to move from cell to cell within a column.

Currently the tab key takes me from cell to cell moving across a row and it seems the return key gives me the option to delete the cell.

Is there a setting I can change somewhere to force the tab function to move from cell to cell within a column?

Answer (score 1):

To get down to the next row, you have to use the **arrow down key**. There is, afaik, no setting to change this nor would I be a big fan of flooding the settings dialogs which such options.

Comment: Thanks for answering.  But the only way I can move within the attribute table is either to physically click on each individual cell or use the tab key which moves me down the row.  Typically I have 100s of polygons with a unique identifier, using the tab key or the mouse is extremely inefficient.

Comment: If this is indeed the case, this should be considered an OSX bug. Please report it.